# Increasing shared memory on OSX to properly install PostgreSQL

Tags: django, macos, postgresql

This is my first stackoverflow post. I am trying to set up PostgreSQL to use with Django. Very new to all of this (took one course in Python in college, now trying to teach myself a little web development).

The installation guide for PostgreSQL says:

---

"Before running the installation, please ensure that your system is 
configured to allow the use of larger amounts of shared memory. Note that
this does not 'reserve' any memory so it is safe to configure much higher
values than you might initially need. You can do this by editting the 
file /etc/sysctl.conf - e.g.

% sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf

On a MacBook Pro with 2GB of RAM, the author's sysctl.conf contains:

kern.sysv.shmmax=1610612736
kern.sysv.shmall=393216
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=32
kern.sysv.shmseg=8
kern.maxprocperuid=512
kern.maxproc=2048

Note that (kern.sysv.shmall * 4096) should be greater than or equal to
kern.sysv.shmmax. kern.sysv.shmmax must also be a multiple of 4096.

Once you have edited (or created) the file, reboot before continuing with 
the installation. If you wish to check the settings currently being used by 
the kernel, you can use the sysctl utility:

% sysctl -a

The database server can now be installed."

---

I am running a fresh-out-of-the-box MBA with 4GB of ram. How to I set this up properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just [download the installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do#osx) and click "ok" to get started. When everything is running, you can always increase memory settings and edit postgresql.conf to get better performance.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Turned out the installer took care of increasing the shared memory all by itself. Crisis averted.